# Overwriting shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, shapefile

I want to be able to overwrite a shapefile if it exists. I think my code needs some tweaking. I am using v10. I am able to delete the actual .shp file but the .dbf, .shx, etc still remain, so if I try to overwrite again, I get an error.

How can I remove all the files associated with the shapefile?

```py
DoesItExist = True
geometry_type = "POLYGON"
print "Your shapefile is being generated."
out_path = raw_input("Enter in path to save shape file: ")
out_name = raw_input("Enter in name of shape file: ")

while DoesItExist == True: 
    if (os.path.exists(os.path.join(out_path, out_name))):
        print "This file already exists. Do you wish to overwrite it?"
         choice = raw_input("Y/N:")
    if (choice == 'Y' or choice == 'y'):
        print "File will be over written"
        os.remove(os.path.join(out_path, out_name))
        #arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name, geometry_type)
        DoesItExist = False
    else:
        print "Choose new file name/location!"
        out_path = raw_input("Enter in file path: ")
        out_name = raw_input("Enter in file name: ")

else:
    print "Shapefile created in: " + str(os.path.join(out_path, out_name))
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name, geometry_type)
    DoesItExist = False
```

Comment: You can use arcpy.Delete_management(shapefile)

Answer (score 19):

You shouldn't have to delete the shapefile. Just add the following lines to your script:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

That will allow `arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management` to overwrite the existing shapefile with all of its associated files (dbf, shx, prj etc.).

Answer (score 8):

There is also the exists function instead of using os. Remember to import env.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "d:/myfolder"
fc = "roads.shp"

#Delete feature class if it exists
if arcpy.Exists(fc):
   arcpy.Delete_management(fc)
```

Comment: Thanks awesomo for the reminder to import env. I'll update my answer.

Comment: oh wow...thanks so much. My error was in forgetting to include/import env. smh@self. Thanks again!

Comment: There's no need to import env specifically.  Just use `arcpy.env.workspace = "d:/myfolder"` after `import arcpy`.